# Exploding and trimming a long string effectively resulting in a single array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, explode

I'm trying to create a messaging system where you can send to a single or multiple users at the same time.
The value which is delivered from my form looks like this:

```
<Username One(1)><Username Two(2)><Username Three(3)>
```

Now, in order for me to post the messages to the database I want to explode and trim this information into three seperate parts. All of which is inside an array.

I want the output to be something like this:

```
Array[0] = 1
Array[1] = 2
Array[2] = 3
```

I've tried using `explode(">", $input_value);` and then use `preg_match`to trim.
However, I end up with two seperate arrays. How can I combine these two and get the result I want? I need it to be as effective as possible as each user should be able to message maximum amount of users at the same time.
Also I would appreciate an easy to understand explanation of regex as I find it a bit confusing.

Comment: Are you getting value within tags

Comment: I'm getting the values inside the parenthesis, yes.

Comment: Why don't you use an existing data structure like json or xml? There are existing methods/extensions to work with those (like `json_decode()` and SimpleXML).

Comment: @JasperN.Brouwer I've never used any of those before. I might take a look into it. Thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$s = '<Username One(1)><Username Two(2)><Username Three(3)>';    
preg_match_all('~\b[\p{L}\p{N}]+(?=\h*\)>)~u', $s, $m);    
print_r($m[0]);

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

`(?=\h*\)>)` is a positive lookahead that matches word before `)>`

Comment: And this works even if the user registers with unique letters such as chinese, æøåöäë and has numbers in the username?

Comment: I used this: `$msg_all_receivers = $_POST['receiver'];
        preg_match_all('~\b\w+(?=\)>)~', $msg_all_receivers, $msg_all_receivers_exp);` and echoed with this: `echo $msg_all_receivers_exp[0].$msg_all_receivers_exp[1];` However, I get the error message: `Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /home/connecti/www/projects/send_message.php on line 328` followed by `Array`

Comment: You have to use: `echo $msg_all_receivers_exp[0][0].$msg_all_receivers_exp[0][1];` Also see updated answer for unicode support.

Comment: Ah, okai, thank you. Does count() work on the underlaying array? or will it just count 1?

Comment: So I would do `$count = count($m[0])`?

Answer (score 1):

Since 1,2,3 are digit in your string. so you can get all the digit from your string

```
<?php
$str="<Username One(1)><Username Two(2)><Username Three(3)>";
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Second thing all string between `() brackets`

```
preg_match_all("/\((.*?)\)/", $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

Comment: This would not future proof if a user registers with numbers. Or am I wrong?